# Request for Feedback: multi-step API Authentication using multiple endpoints

Tags: api, authentication, architecture, microservices, api-design

I am building an API that will authenticate using the following flow.

Endpoints:

- `WWW:/login` - this is the HTML5 frontend using JS ajax calls
- `API:/check_password` - checks email/password combo.
- `API:/check_otp` - checks OTP (One-time password) for user.
- `API:/login` - sets authentication session cookie

**Assumption:**

- `API:/check_otp` will always and only ever be called after `API:/check_password`.
- Ignore CSRF attacks and XSS attacks.
- Even if the frontend (WWW:/login) is malicious, the API will only work with valid credentials and/or `action_tokens`.
- I am aware of OAuth2, JWTs, and RESTful APIs.  My question is not about RESTful API.

**When logging in, the flow would be this:**

- `WWW:/login` submits email and password to `API:/check_password`.
- If the credentials are valid, `API:/check_password` will return an `action_token` and `mfa_status` (stands for Multi-factor authentication).

  - If `mfa_status` is 0, that means MFA is not enabled.
  - If `mfa_status` is 1, that means MFA is enabled.
- If `(mfa_status === 1)`, then WWW:/login will call `API:/check_otp` and pass it the `action_token` received from `API:/check_password` as well as the OTP.

  - If the OTP and `action_token` are valid, then `API:/check_otp` will return a new `action_token`.
- If `(mfa_status === 0)` or `API:/check_otp` returns a valid `action_token`, then `WWW:/login` will call `API:/login` and pass to it the `email` and `action_token`.

To me, this means the frontend does NOT need to save the password or OTP anywhere in its data stores (localstorage, indexeddb, etc). It also means it can immediately remove the `action_token` from its data stores.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Is this secure?
2. Are there any flaws in this logic?
3. Did I miss anything?

Many thanks for an interesting and thorough discussion!

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern directly maps to OAuth2, why would you not use a tried-and-true security pattern like OAuth2?  You are trying to rebuild it for some reason...  your action_token is the same as the OAuth access token.

Also, you will need to keep your access token for subsequent calls to protected resources (you know like OAuth does)...

All you are doing is making more work for yourself by not either using an out-of-the-box OAuth library, or obfuscating the process to make the next person to update this code cranky with you.